# Linux: how to move the installed directory to other place?

Tags: linux, installation

I am using LINUX machine.

I have install a folder in directory `/mnt/sdc1` by running `./configure->make->make install`. Right now, I want to move that folder out of `/mnt/sdc` to `~/New_Place`.

What is the most convienent way to do this? Do I simply `mv` or do I do `cp`?

Do I have to `uninstall` first?

Answer (score 0):

`mv` changes the location of a file or directory.

`cp` copies a file or directory, and leaves the original alone.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question my friend.